# Displaying specific posts from query thumbnail outside div

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to display thumbnails inside a div from a query, but the thumbnail is outside the div and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here is my code:

```
<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array(26844,26829),
    'post_type'              => array( 'wedstrijd' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'published' ),
);

// The Query
$shquery = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $shquery->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $shquery->have_posts() ) {
        $shquery->the_post();
        echo '<div class="wed_thumb">' . the_post_thumbnail('et-pb-post-main-image') . '</div>';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`the_post_thumbnail` will echo it, You should Use [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) instead to return image.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Only problem now is that the size 'et-pb-post-main-image' doesn't work. Is size even possible with get_thepost_thumbnail? I also tried $size = 'et-pb-post-main-image' to no avail.

Comment: get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'et-pb-post-main-image');